# Надо ли синонимизировать [show] и [отображения]?

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две подозрительно похожие метки:

- [show](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/show) (6 вопросов)
- [отображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (6 вопросов)

Может быть их надо синонимизировать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопросов довольно мало, но уже сейчас можно заметить, что используются они в разных смыслах. Отображения — математические, show - для показа/скрытия виджетов/контролов. Поэтому, объединять их точно не стоит. Рекомендую в дальнейшем предлагать более наполненные метки (с бОльшим количеством вопросов) и проводить некоторый предварительный анализ их использования. Не стоит опираться только лишь на прямой англо-русский перевод.